# I want to update breadcrums based my filters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am new in web development. I want to append bread crumbs based on click. this script is basically added only one like from the first li if I select second then it update second I want it to add more like if I checked the first name then add like home/ first and if I click on second it update Home/first/second in this format I want and both of them together but nothing works like if I have selected the first two from the first filter and three four from second then it will look like Home/first/second/third/four  and also remove from breadcrumbs if I second click and vice versa

```js
    $('.categories a, .second li input ').on('click', function() {
      var $this = $(this),
          $bc = $('<div class="item"></div>');

      $this.parents('li').each(function(n, li) {
          var $a = $(li).children('a').clone();
          $bc.prepend(' / ', $a);
      });
        $('.breadcrumb').html( $bc.prepend('<a href="#home">Home</a>') );
        return false;
    })
```

Comment: I can hardly make out anything. Please state the exact problem and what you want

Comment: I want to update the bread crumbs for both li a and input checkbox together the above code not working only Li works but it only adds one link

Comment: Please at least add some punctuation, and lay out the points you want to achieve clearly, maybe using bullet points or numbers. This is just one giant incomprehensible sentence right now. Make it easy for us to help you by making your question as easy as possible to understand. People will usually not take the time to try and work out what you are talking about. Instead they will find another question they can understand.

Comment: Mydomain / All
/ Home /
First Filter
Audio
Health
Home
LifeStyle
Second Filter
 CLICK AND GROW
 KRONABY SWEDEN
 MEURAL
 MOTIV
 MUSE
 QUIP
 SOLOS SMART GLASSES

Comment: Ps. What have you tried to do so far? We like to help people here, not just do everything for them. I know you are new to web development but that doesn't stop you at least trying to write it. Please show your current attempt.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$('.categories a, .second li label input ').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      $bc = $('<span class="breadcrumb-separator"> / </span>');

  $this.parents('li').each(function(n, li) {
      var $a = $('li a', '.second li label input').clone();
      $bc.prepend(' / ', $a);
  });
    $('.breadcrumb').html( $bc.prepend('<nav class="breadcrumb"><a href="mydomain.com">Mydomain</a><span class="breadcrumb-separator"> / </span>All  ') );
    return false;
})
</script>

Comment: Please have  a look none of my scripts is working

Comment: Please stop writing things in comments and use the [edit] link. I tried to fix your sentences but gave up since I can't figure out what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $('.breadcrumb').html( $bc.prepend('<nav class="breadcrumb"><a href="mydomain.com">Mydomain</a><span class="breadcrumb-separator"> / </span>All  </nav>') );
```

Try using this

Comment: My domain / All
/ Home /
It was displayed like this I want them in a row and if I select Audio Health and home it will display like My domain / All /audio/health/ home and if I again click on home it removes it from breadcrumbs

Comment: please help I need to like this for checkbox input too.